# Verilog For loop: wrong initial value

Tags: verilog

I am trying to use for loops in my verilog design, and for some reason the inital value of the for loop is not set right. 
I tried writing a simple for loop in verilog and checked the simulation. I still get the wrong initial value.

This is the simple for loop i tried:

```
integer j; 
always @(posedge clk)
begin 
  for (j=0; j< 16; j=j+1)
  begin 
    count <= count+1;
  end 
end
```

In the simulation, the first transition of j is from X to 16. 
Could someone help me with this?

Comment: This **for loop** completes within the one clock cycle i.e. **j** increments from 0 to 16 with in one clock cycle. Hence, you can only see the final value of j which is 16. and **j=x** initially since it is not initialized before.

Answer (score 0):

As [ssjr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3951497/ssgr) said in the comments `always @(posedge clk)` represents a flip-flop everything contained with in it is completed in a simulation of a clock cycle.

To count to 15 you might have:

```
reg [3:0] count;
always @(posedge clk) begin 
  if (count < 5'd15) begin 
    count <= count+1;
  end 
end
```